# How to use ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist

I have problem with some basic Android knowledge. **My problem is I don't know how to fill in a value from `ArrayList`.** Currently I have 2 applications, one application sending an information through intent, and another application receiving the information.

In the first application, it will receive some information for specific printer's error. All the information I have to show in other application as a notification. The notification (the second application) I have implemented it, it is can show the notification. The notification is carried by a `String` type and with intent it can sent to second apps.

I have one method called `updateUI()`. Because I have to keep updated the Interface and the information for my first application, I'm using a service. So, `updateUI()` in every certain seconds will be called.

I have ArrayList, called `error`. This list will collect all the information:

```
ArrayList<String> error;
```

I have declared the notification in first application:

```
String notification;
```

Right now I want to fill this String from ArrayList. Before doing that I have declared temporary String called temp. This string will avoid the same notification that will be sent to notification app when `updateUI()` has been called again.

```
for (int i = 0; i < error.size(); i++) {
    if (error.get(i) != null) {
        notification= error.get(i);
        if (notification.equals(temp)) {
            notification = null;
        } 
        else 
        {
            temp = notification;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I sent the notification:

```
Intent broadCastIntent = new Intent("SendMessage");
broadCastIntent.putExtra("ERROR", notification);
sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent);
```

If the arrayList contains one element, it works fine. But if there are 2 events happen, so the error array have 2 elements, It will only show the second element.I want to sent the first element as a notification followed by second elements.

Example:
in `error` has 2 elements

```
error = {"Ink Black is empty","Ink Magenta is Empty",null,null};
```

when we go to `for` statement

**First index:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < error.size(); i++) {
            if (error.get(0) != null) {  ---------> Error.get[0] = "Ink Black..."
                notification= error.get(i); ---> notification = "Ink Black..."
                if (notification.equals(temp)) {
                    notification = null;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    temp = notification;---> temp= "Ink Black..."
                }
            }
        }
```

**Second index:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < error.size(); i++) {
        if (error.get(1) != null) { --------> Error.get[1] = "Ink Magenta..."
            notification= error.get(1);----> notification = "Ink Magenta..."
            if (notification.equals(temp)) {---> "(Ink Magenta...".equals("Ink Black...")
                notification = null; 
            } 
            else 
            {
                temp = notification; ----->temp= "Ink Magenta..."
            }
        }
    }
```

After went to `for` statement the notification only contained "Ink Magenta..". Because of that the notification apps only show :Ink Magenta..." Anybody knows how to distinguish elements of `Arraylist` so I can sent it one by one?

I have tried without for statement, but I have got null pointer if there is only one element inside the `arraylist`.

```
if (!error.get(0).isEmpty())
        {
            if (error.get(0).equals(temp))
            {
                if (!error.get(1).isEmpty() && !error.get(1).equals(tempA))
                {
                    notification = error.get(1);
                    tempA = error.get(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    notification= null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                notification= error.get(0);
                temp = error.get(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            notification= null;
        }
```

Anybody knows how to solve my problem? So that I can use other elements

Answer (score 1):

You have not **initialized your ArrayList**. So, without initializing if you are trying to work around with an object it will end you up in Null pointer exception.

Try to initialize your list..

```
error = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And, then if you want to add an element to ArrayList you have to add like:

```
error.add("Ink Black is empty");
error.add("Ink Magenta is Empty");
```

Comment: initialization is not an issue here read the question once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!error.get(1).isEmpty() && !error.get(1).equals(tempA))
```

you need to check whether either size of your arraylist is greater than 1, or check if error.get(i) != null

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure uniqueness for the items that you add to your arraylist, don't use arraylist. Use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (for example HashSet) because Set is `A collection that contains no duplicate elements.`

After you have done getting notifications, that is adding items to your set object, call `sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent)` for each item